# Order By on HasMany relationship Laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

In my Laravel 5 app, I've got a one-to-many relationship between two models.

My models are: `User` and `Message`.

I can access to messages from one user with:

```
$messages = $user->messages
```

How can I order these messages by creation date?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following should work.

```
$messages = $user->messages()->orderBy('created_at')->get();
```

Comment: Works perfectly!!! So if I have to "query" in a relationship i have to use parentheses, and if only I have to retrieve the results I can get them without parentheses ?

Comment: I am not exactly sure - but yeah.