# Doing an orderBy through relationship

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, model

I've got a pretty normal table structure like this:

```
 Order
,----------,
|id        | 
|order_num |
`----------`

 OrderItem
,---------,
|id       |
|order_id |
|item_id  |
`---------`

 Item
,----------,
|id        |
|item_name |
|price     |
`----------`
```

A classic `Order` table, `Item` table, and adding items to an order via an `OrderItem` table. However, what I want to be able to do is get a list of `OrderItem` records that are ordered by `Item`'s item_name column from the Order model.

```
class Order extends Model 
{
     public function order_items()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('App\OrderItem');   <-- How can I get this ordered by the item name?
     }
}
```

So it's sort of an `->orderThrough` (if such a thing existed). Is there a clean way to accomplish this?

Comment: Order::find($x)->order_items->orderBy('xxx'); or in the definition of the relation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order By on HasMany relationship Laravel 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366694/order-by-on-hasmany-relationship-laravel-5)

Comment: There should be `...order_items()->...`. See the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships).

Comment: Not quite, because I'm going an extra layer through the relationship, not on the child table directly. It may not even be possible the way I'm doing it. I'm not sure.

Comment: From the Order model, I want to retrieve OrderItem records, but I want them to be ordered by Item's name. So it's kind of a weird nested thing going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Order extends Model 
{
     public function order_items()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('App\OrderItem')->orderBy('name');
     }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. I get invalid column 'name'. The 'name' column doesn't exist on App\OrderItem, but rather on App\Item.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to build a relationship to a pivot table. Your relationship should be defined to the items like this:

```
class Order extends Model 
{
     public function items()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'OrderItem');
     }
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
$order = new App\Order::find(1234);
$items = $order->items()->orderBy('item_name')->get();
```

---

If you really want the order defined inside the relationship:

```
class Order extends Model 
{
     public function items()
     {
         return $this->hasMany('App\Item', 'OrderItem')->orderBy('item_name');
     }
}

$order = new App\Order::find(1234);
$items = $order->items;
```